# athena query date and time stamp logic for 1 hour

Tags: java, sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

i am trying to get the data from s3 bucket with CSV file based on the 1 hour time interval but date and time stamp is two different column so can you please let me know how to write the athena query

date and Timestamp  are string

date : 6/18/2023

Timestamp : 20:30:24

```
private static final String SIMPLE_ATHENA_QUERY_TIME = "SELECT * FROM dmat_db.dmat_kpi_tbldmat_csv_file_processed_bucket where date > '6/18/2023' and Timestamp > '6/18/2023' - interval '1' hour;";
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Query Failed to run with Error Message:
> TYPE_MISMATCH: line 1:119: Cannot apply operator: varchar(9) -
> interval day to second    at
> com.dmat.kpi.controller.DMATKpiController.waitForQueryToComplete(DMATKpiController.java:103)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> com.dmat.kpi.controller.DMATKpiController.AthenaQuery(DMATKpiController.java:65)
> ~[classes/:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to subtract time from a string, not a timestamp object. You could use `date_sub` function to get the date.

```java
private static final String SIMPLE_ATHENA_QUERY_TIME = "
    SELECT * FROM dmat_db.dmat_kpi_tbldmat_csv_file_processed_bucket
        WHERE 'date' > '2023-06-18' 
        AND 'Timestamp' > date_sub('2023-06-18', 1, 'hour');";
```

Something like this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should not compare dates/timestamps as strings, especially when some parts are encoded with variable length (i.e. month which is one or two digits). Parse the timestamp and then compare. Sample SQL will look like:

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(date, timestamp) as (
    values ('6/18/2023', '20:30:24')
)

-- sample query 
SELECT *
FROM dataset
where date_parse(date || ' ' || timestamp, '%c/%e/%Y %T') > timestamp '2023-06-18' - interval '1' hour;
```

Read more:

- [MySQL Date Functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#mysql-date-functions)